# How to blur an image with win2D?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml, win2d

I want to blur this image:

```
<Image x:Name="pic"  Stretch="Fill" Margin="3,-43,0,-46"/>
```

when this method is called:

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    pic.Source=CertainImage;
    //blur this image
}
```

Should I use GaussianBlurEffect? How to use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is [BackdropBlurBrush](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/brushes/backdropblurbrush) in Windows Community Toolkit.

```xml
<Grid>
  <Image  Height="400"  Source="ms-appx:///Assets/Photos/BigFourSummerHeat.jpg"/>
  <Border x:Name="bor" Visibility="Collapsed" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" > 
    <Border.Background>
      <media:BackdropBlurBrush Amount="3.43" />
     </Border.Background>
  </Border>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    bor.Visibility = Visibility.Visible; //or change the amount of blur effect
}
```